# Add a dot between javascript output

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following javascript to detect iOS Version

```
var iOS = parseFloat(
    ('' + (/CPU.*OS ([0-9_]{1,5})|(CPU like).*AppleWebKit.*Mobile/i.exec(navigator.userAgent) || [0,''])[1])
    .replace('undefined', '3_2').replace('_', '.').replace('_', '')
) || false;
```

the problem is that the script is showing 7.06 instead of 7.0.6

how can i add a "." between the last 2 numbers?

tried messing with the code and changing some stuff but couldn't make it

i'm newbie in javascript, thank you :)

Comment: Well, you can't have a float with two decimal points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that parseFloat masks the real problem, namely that your replace is slightly off. You start out correct, as in

```
('' + (/CPU.*OS ([0-9_]{1,5})|(CPU like).*AppleWebKit.*Mobile/gi.exec(navigator.userAgent) || [0,''])[1])
```

yields `"7_0_6"`. However, the replace only hits the first `_` and converts this string to `"7.0_6"` (the next "_" -> "" removes the last underscore which is how you get 7.06). Make the replace do a global replace and it will get both.

```
(('' + (/CPU.*OS ([0-9_]{1,5})|(CPU like).*AppleWebKit.*Mobile/i.exec(navigator.userAgent) || [0,''])[1])
.replace('undefined', '3_2').replace(/_/gi, '.').replace(/_/gi, '')
) || false;
```

Will yield `"7.0.6"`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is this: `parseFloat`. You want a string, not a number. A number can have only one decimal point.

Just try:

```
var iOS = ('' + (/CPU.*OS ([0-9_]{1,5})|(CPU like).*AppleWebKit.*Mobile/i.exec(navigator.userAgent) || [0,''])[1])
.replace('undefined', '3_2').replace('_', '.').replace('_', '') || false;
```

Comment: @F0u4d, what is the original `navigator.userAgent`?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by original

Comment: @F0u4d, nothing really, except that it is the string you "started" with. What is `navigator.userAgent`?